# How to save gl_speech_op to an object in R

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform

How do you save `gl_speech_op` output to an object within the R?

I successfully ran [GoogleLanguageR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleLanguageR/index.html) to convert an audio file to text within the Google Cloud Platform. I can see the output but I don't know how to save the output to an object within R Studio.

Sample code is below. I am using R Notebook.

```
library(googleLanguageR)
library(tidyverse)

###let's get Craig Watkins

gl_auth("D:/Admin/Documents/Google API JSON Authenticate/My Project two test-db5d6330925e.json")
watkins <- gl_speech("gs://testtwoibm/craig watkins 2018_05_07_14_08_08.flac", 
                     encoding = c("FLAC"), sampleRateHertz = 44100, languageCode = "en-US", 
                     maxAlternatives = 1L, asynch = TRUE)
## Send to gl_speech_op() for status or finished result
gl_speech_op(watkins)
```

[RStudio notebook output showing converted speech to text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T2nh.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in R to save any output of an operation to an object in R is assigning it via the assignment operator `<-`

In your case, you would only assign it to an object like this:

`transcript <- gl_speech_op(watkins)`

One small reminder: This will also work if the asynchronous API request hasn't finished transcribing yet. However, your object will not contain any information. In your case it will be any list of 2 with two NULL elements. If finished, the object will contain both the transcript and the timings.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want the output as a text. If this is the case, then you can use `capture.output`:

```
new_obj = capture.output(gl_speech_op(watkins))
new_obj
```